# tkinter entry command based on number of characters entered?

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings, tkinter-entry

Tkinter key binding using `Tf.bind('<Return>', function)` will trigger a function with the `<Return>` (Enter) key from the entry widget. Is there a parameter that will trigger the function based on the number of characters entered within the entry widget?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a parameter that will trigger the function based on the number of characters entered within the entry widget?

No, there is not. Your bound function can easily check how many characters are in the widget and simply not do anything until the limit has been reached.